# child not detach from parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My document entity class is

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Document_Directory")
    public class DocumentDirectoryEntity{

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private DocumentDirectoryEntity parentDirectory;
    private List<DocumentDirectoryEntity> childDirectoryList;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="name", length=250, nullable= false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_dir_id")
    public DocumentDirectoryEntity getParentDirectory() {
        return parentDirectory;
    }
    public void setParentDirectory(DocumentDirectoryEntity parentDirectory) {
        this.parentDirectory = parentDirectory;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentDirectory", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
    public List<DocumentDirectoryEntity> getChildDirectoryList() {
        return childDirectoryList;
    }
    public void setChildDirectoryList(List<DocumentDirectoryEntity> childDirectoryList) {
        this.childDirectoryList = childDirectoryList;
    }
}
```

I want delete a document but before delete, i want to change its child's parent. But I am not able to do it. code is:-

```
DocumentDirectoryEntity documentDirectoryEntity = documentDirectoryDao.findById(1);
DocumentDirectoryEntity documentDirectoryEntity1 = documentDirectoryDao.findById(2);
List<DocumentDirectoryEntity> childDirectoryList = documentDirectoryEntity.getChildDirectoryList();
DocumentDirectoryEntity childDirectory = childDirectoryList.get(0);
childDirectory.setParentDirectory(documentDirectoryEntity1);
documentDirectoryDao.update(childDirectory);
documentDirectoryDao.delete(documentDirectoryEntity);
```

when i delete object documentDirectoryEntity then childDirectory row is also removed.

Comment: You have to remove the chile from the parent as well

Comment: I also tried documentDirectoryEntity.getChildDirectoryList().remove(childDirectory); documentDirectoryDao.update(documentDirectoryEntity); before documentDirectoryDao.delete(documentDirectoryEntity);. But problem was still same

Comment: Do you have cascade all on childDirectory?

Comment: yes with orphanremoval  cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true